# Create a SDK with Android Studio 1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I want to create an Android SDK.

To create this one I begin to create a library Android in Android Studio 1.1.

How can I test it?

And how can I create a .jar file with all the dependency ?
I know the .aar is the good way to do this but the eclipse user can't use it, can it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

İn your android studio project, there should be 2 module. One of them is your library module which is created as a library module from new module screen and an activity which is simple screen to test it (Lets call it sample module).

To test your library module in sample module, you need to add 'compile project(':library')' to build.gradle which is belongs to sample module.

To compile it as a jar you can use 'maven project' tab from right of the screen. There are many of build options. In default it generates your build to outputs in your project folder.

Good luck there

Comment: When I try to add 'compile project(':library')'  
I have this Error:(28, 0) Project with path ':library' could not be found in project ':app'.

And If I try to compile it I can't because isn't a 'marven project'

Comment: compile project(':your library module name') Are you sure that your library module named as "library"

Comment: Do you know why my library isn't a maven project?

Comment: I didn't use maven, I just use 
task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/Jar/AdBerries_SDK.jar'
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('build/Jar/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename ('classes.jar', 'myJar.jar')
} in the build.gradle.

with this I have a Jar and I add my dependencies to the application project add mi SDK all run correctly

Comment: I am glad that i can help you. Enjoy :)

Comment: I have already another problem, if you have time : www.stackoverflow.com/questions/29281773/